# how to push all objects keys to a separate array in array using angular or javascript?

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, angular5, javascript-objects

I have array of objects like this

```
let array = [
 {'name' : 'Jack', 'age':23},
 {'name': 'Robin', 'age':25}
];
```

and I want an array like this

```
[
 ['Jack',23],
 ['Robin',25]
]
```

I tried this code

```
var myArr = []; 

var input = [
  {name : 'Jack', age : 23},
  {name : 'Robin', age : 25}
];

input.forEach((item,index)=>{
  for (var k in item) { 
    myArr.push(item[k]);
  }
})
```

But it is producing result like this

```
["Jack", 23, "Robin", 25]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simply pass `Object.values` as callback to `.map()`:

```js
let array = [
 {'name' : 'Jack', 'age':23},
 {'name': 'Robin', 'age':25}
];

let result = array.map(Object.values);

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: The order in which you get the values in Object.values or Object.keys or `for ... in` or `for ... of` from an object (other than a Map) is not guaranteed and there is no specification in JS for the order. So if you want to convert `{'name' : 'Jack', 'age':23}` specifically to `['Jack',23]` then this answer will work by accident but not because it's guaranteed by JS specification. You should never write code relying on the current order of getting keys from objects because it can be changed and will break if that happens.

Answer (score 4):

```js
let array = [
 {'name' : 'Jack', 'age':23},
 {'name': 'Robin', 'age':25}
];

arrayOfValues = array.map(({name, age})=> ([name, age]))

console.log(arrayOfValues)
```

@HMR Thank you very much for sharing the valuable information.

The order in which you get the values in Object.values or Object.keys or for ... in or for ... of from an object (other than a Map) is not guaranteed and there is no specification in JS for the order.

[More Information](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in#Array_iteration_and_for...in)

Comment: The order in which you get the values in Object.values or Object.keys or `for ... in` or `for ... of` from an object (other than a Map) is not guaranteed and there is no specification in JS for the order. So if you want to convert `{'name' : 'Jack', 'age':23}` specifically to `['Jack',23]` then this is the only valid answer.

Comment: You're Correct @HMR

Comment: Mohammed pls consider adding @HMR's point as your explanation so that others are also educated with the same and are not mislead by the accepted answer.

Answer (score 2):

This would be `Array.map` and `Object.values` like below

```js
let array = [
 {'name' : 'Jack', 'age':23},
 {'name': 'Robin', 'age':25}
];

let res = array.map(d => Object.values(d))

console.log(res)
```

Comment: The order in which you get the values in Object.values or Object.keys or `for ... in` or `for ... of` from an object (other than a Map, Set or Array) is not guaranteed and there is no specification in JS for the order. So if you want to convert `{'name' : 'Jack', 'age':23}` specifically to `['Jack',23]` then this answer will work by accident but not because it's guaranteed by JS specification. You should never write code relying on the current order of getting keys from objects because it can be changed and will break if that happens.